# Why and when is Eclipse putting Maven dependencies in the CLASSPATH and not in the MODULEPATH?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, java-platform-module-system

I have a Java 11 project which defines a module-info.java and is compliant with JPMS - except that it requires unnamed modules from other developers that did not yet care about JPMS.

When I put the Maven dependencies in the module path, that is, in the `.classpath` of Eclipse I have

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

then everything works just fine. However, when I select Maven -> Update Project in Eclipse, then Eclipse will remove the line

```
        <attribute name="module" value="true"/>
```

After that, the project shows an error in Eclipse ("*The type xxx cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class file.*").

How can I tell Maven to keep the `<attribute name="module" value="true"/>` upon "Maven -> Update Project...".

(Eclipse version is 2020-03)

Comment: Please show a minimal example to reproduce this issue (`pom.xml`, `module-info.java` and Java code).

Comment: Have you tried opening "Configure build path" dialogue and dragging the  "Maven Dependencies" items from the class path to the module path?

Comment: Yes. I tried that. It works in the sense that <ou can change this manually. But once you select Maven->Update Project Eclipse will change it back. The question is about "Maven -> Update Project..."

Answer (score 2):

I use this in my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <release>${java.version}</release>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
        <debug>true</debug>
        <debuglevel>source,lines</debuglevel>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <modulePath>
            <dependency>org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api</dependency>
            <dependency>org.apache.logging.log4j.core:log4j-core</dependency>
            ... etc ...
        </modulePath>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But, unfortunately, some `modulePath > dependency` work fine, others do not.