# Maven putting other module on classpath instead of modulepath - how to correct?

Tags: maven, multi-module, java-platform-module-system

I have a Maven multi-module project.

- `Module 1` generates a jar file which does not use Java 9 modules
- `Module 2` has a `module-info.java` file and uses Module 1's Jar as an automatic module

When I compile Module 1 and then Module 2, everything is fine. When I build using the parent pom, Module 2 fails because it cannot find Module 1 as a Java 9 automatic module.

Looking at the output of the `maven-compiler-plugin`, I see this when I build the parent pom:

```
Classpath:
 /path/to/myproject/module2/target/classes
 /path/to/myproject/module1/target/classes
Modulepath:
 /path/to/other/jarFile1.jar
 /path/to/other/jarFile2.jar
Source roots:
 /path/to/myproject/module2/src/main/java
```

**Module 1 has been included on the classpath as a series of .class files, rather than on the Module path as a jar.**

In the pom files I have:

- parent `pom.xml`
- `module1.pom` -> generates `myproject:module1:v1:jar`
- `module2.pom` -> dependency on `myproject:module1:v1:jar`, generates `myproject:module2:v1:jar`

How can I tell Maven to

1. not include module1 on the classpath as a series of classes?
2. include `module1.jar` in the modulepath?

I have tried both 3.8.1 and 3.10.1 and have tried the  elements recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67291116/68283), but it doesn't help.

Comment: First the given linke does not contain correct information because modulePath configuration does simply not exist in maven-compiler-plugin. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/ furthermore can you make a full working example on github or alike.. Module1 will not being pot on the classpath as a series of classes only as a jar file.. also the question which Maven version do you use? Also can you explain more in detail: ` Module 1's Jar as an automatic module`.. ? Have you define the automatic module name in the manifest of module1 ???